# Find all possible values of $ a^3 + b^3$ if $a^2+b^2=ab=4$.

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Find all possible values of $a^3 + b^3$ if $a^2+b^2=ab=4$.

From $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)=(a+b)(4-4)=(a+b)0$. Then we know $a^3+b^3=0$. 
If $a=b=0$, it is conflict with $a^2+b^2=ab=4$.
If $a\neq0$ and $b\neq0$, then $a$ and $b$ should be one positive and one negative. This contradict with $ab$=4.

I don't know the solution.

Any help please.

Comment: Are a and b allowed to be complex? If so, what happens when you multiply $a^3+b^3=0$ by $b^3$? $a^3$?

Answer (score 5):

There are no solutions in the real numbers.

Plotting $a^2+b^2=4$ on a graph, we get a circle radius 2. Plotting $ab=4$ on the same graph, we get a hyperbola which goes through $(2,2)$ (with the negative side going through $(-2,-2)$) which does not intersect the circle.

[image]

---

A tag of "recreational mathematics" wouldn't usually cause me to go looking for complex solutions unless they were apparent from the setup. However [Lythia](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/166215/lythia)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1186333/206402) correctly identifies that the options in the complex plane are restricted to $a$ and $b$ choosing from the $6^{th}$ roots of $-64$. Since $ab=4$, $a$ and $b$ must be complex conjugates. The $a^2+b^2=4$ requirement additionally means that $a$ and $b$ cannot be $\pm 2i$, giving the four answer pairs of $a=\pm \sqrt 3\pm i$ and $b=a^*$.

Allowing complex $a$ and $b$ rescues the question's original analysis and reinstates the answer of $a^3+b^3 = 0$.

Comment: There *are* solutions.  The problem did not say that $a$ and $b$ had to be real.

Answer (score 2):

To give a different perspective, I can't find anywhere in the problem statement which states $a$ and $b$ must be real. Therefore, assume $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$. Then the equation $a^3+b^3=0$ along with the condition $ab=4$ implies, by multiplying both sides by either $a^3$ or $b^3$ that $a^6+64 = 0$ and $b^6+64=0$. Therefore, 
$$ a = \pm\sqrt[6]{-64} = \pm2\sqrt[6]{-1},\\  b= \pm\sqrt[6]{-64} = \pm2\sqrt[6]{-1}.$$
As $a$ and $b$ are multiples of sixth roots of unity, there are six choices for each. Not all choices are valid since the condition $a^2+b^2=4$ must also be met. For example 
$$a=b=\sqrt{3}+i$$
does not work since then $a^2+b^2=4+4\sqrt{3}i$. However, the choice 
$$a=\sqrt{3}+i, b=\sqrt{3}-i$$
works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there were real solutions to $a^2 + b^2 = ab = 4$. Then $$0 \leq (a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2 = (a^2 + b^2) - 2ab = -4$$ which is a a contradiction. Thus there cannot be real $a, b$ satisfying the requirements.

Comment: ...thus there cannot be *real* $a,b$ satisfying the requirements.

Comment: Indeed you are correct

Answer (score 1):

It is given that $a^{2} + b^{2} = ab =4$ and the goal is to determine all values of $a^{3} + b^{3}$. Now, it is seen that $a^{3} + b^{3} = (a+b)(a^{2} - ab + b^{2}) = 0$. So far the set of equations becomes
\begin{align}
a^{3} + b^{3} &= 0 \\
a^{2} + b^{2} &= 4 \\
ab &= 4.
\end{align}
From the first, multiply by $a^{3}$ to obtain $0 = a^{6} + (ab)^{3} = a^{6} + 2^{6}$ which yields $a = \pm 2 e^{\pi i/6 \pm 2n \pi i}$. Since $ab=4$ then yields $b = \pm 2 e^{-\pi i/6 \pm 2n\pi i}$. In both cases $n \geq 0$. The possible values of $a$ are
\begin{align}
a \in \{ 2 e^{\pi i/6 + 2n \pi i}, 2 e^{\pi i/6 - 2n \pi i}, - 2 e^{\pi i/6 + 2n \pi i}, - 2 e^{\pi i/6 - 2n \pi i} \}
\end{align}
and for $b$
\begin{align}
b \in \{ 2 e^{-\pi i/6 + 2n \pi i}, 2 e^{-\pi i/6 - 2n \pi i}, - 2 e^{-\pi i/6 + 2n \pi i}, - 2 e^{-\pi i/6 - 2n \pi i} \}
\end{align}
In view of these two sets of values it is seen that the sets must be taken in order of signs, ie the sets $(a, b) \in \{(+,+), (-,-)\}$,
\begin{align}
a^{3} + b^{3} &= 2 (\pm 2)^{3} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 0 \\
a^{2} + b^{2} &= 2 (\pm 2)^{2} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = 4 \\
ab &= (\pm 2)^{2} = 4.
\end{align}

Comment: Do all of your combinations satisfy $a^2+b^2=4$?

Comment: @MichaelGrant taken in the order of signs, as added, the equations are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

As has been observed, one approach to this problem is to solve the equations over the complex numbers, and then check directly that $a^3+b^3=0$ in all cases.  However, it's both useful and more general to observe that the conclusion can be reached without actually solving the equations: since $a^2+b^2=a b$, we have

> $(*)\ \ a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-a b + b^2)=0.$

The problem makes sense over any field  -- in fact in any commutative ring with $1$ (this condition is only needed so that "$4$" makes sense.)  In addition to being simple, an advantage of the solution $(*)$ is that it works regardless of the setting.  This is relevant, since the problem did not specify a domain for $a$ and $b$, so a solution based on calculating the roots in a particular context involves an inherent assumption.

For example, in the field ${\Bbb F}_{37}$ (i.e., the integers mod $37$), the equations have the four solutions $(a,b)$=$(9,21)$, $(16,28)$, $(21,9)$, and $(28,16)$.  You can check that $a^3+b^3=0$ in each case, but you're back to square one when faced with ${\Bbb F}_{61}$.

Comment: The question already infers from the hypotheses that $\,0\,$ is the only possible value of $\,a^3+b^3.\,$ Hence the answer is $\{0\}$ if the equations are solvable in the ambient ring, and $\{\,\}$ if not.